# How can I allow out of stock product to checkout in magento?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

We want to allow customer to order out of stock products, Is there any solution by this we can allow customer to checkout out of stock products?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is an option available in admin.

Just go to your manage product page and in inventory tab you can find **Backorders** dropdown, choose allow quantity below 0 option and save, now customer can order out of stock product also.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

You can see the location where you need to set "Allow quantity below zero".

Thanks.